# Trying to convert a class based component to a functional with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, mern

Much of the refactoring has worked except this;

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ExerciseItems from './ExerciseItems'
import axios from 'axios';


export default function ExercisesList() {
 
  const [exercises, setExercises] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/exercises/')
        .then(response => {
        setExercises(response.data)
        })
    }, [])

    const exerciseList = () => {
        exercises.map(currentexercise => {
            return <ExerciseItems 
                exercise={currentexercise} 
                key={currentexercise._id}
            />;
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
           {exerciseList}
        </div>
    )
  }
```

The original code is as follows;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const Exercise = props => (
  <tr>
    <td>{props.exercise.username}</td>
    <td>{props.exercise.description}</td>
    <td>{props.exercise.duration}</td>
    <td>{props.exercise.date.substring(0,10)}</td>
  </tr>
)

export default class ExercisesList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {exercises: []};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/exercises/')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ exercises: response.data })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

  exerciseList() {
    return this.state.exercises.map(currentexercise => {
      return <Exercise exercise={currentexercise} deleteExercise={this.deleteExercise} key={currentexercise._id}/>;
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.exerciseList() }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The child component receiving the props has nothing more than a few data rows to display the info, and much of (working) code has been redacted to bypass the posting conditions here. The issue I'm facing is that rendering `exerciseList` simply does not work. Would appreciate any help on solving this.

Comment: can you also attach the ExerciseItems component

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of `return` the result of the map function inside `exerciseList`

```
const exerciseList = () => {
    return exercises.map((currentexercise) => {
```

Also you have to call the `exerciseList` function in the last line:

```
return <div>{exerciseList()}</div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues

```
const exerciseList = () => {
        exercises.map(currentexercise => {
            return <ExerciseItems 
                exercise={currentexercise} 
                key={currentexercise._id}
            />;
        })
    }
```

transform to

```
const exerciseList = () => {
        return exercises.map(currentexercise => {
            return <ExerciseItems 
                exercise={currentexercise} 
                key={currentexercise._id}
            />;
        })
    }
```

and

```
return (
        <div>
           {exerciseList}
        </div>
    )
```

to

```
return (
        <div>
           {exerciseList()}
        </div>
    )
```